# IONIC 2 InAppBrowser is not working in IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic2, inappbrowser

> **This below code is working fine in Android. but, it doesn't works in IOS.**
>
> We think the **browser.executeScript** is not working here. here we are getting the **redirection url from the API as a html content (this.paymentGatewayDetails)** and we need to open that. It works fine in android.
>
> 1. trying this in IOS 11.0 phone.
> 2. IONIC 2.2 version
> 3. Plugin @ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.3.2"
>
> This is the function we are trying to execute.

```
callGateway() {  
 return new Promise(
   (resolve, reject) => {

    let injected = false;

    if (!this.paymentGatewayDetails) {
      reject("PG_DET_INVALID")
    }

 const browser = this.iab.create("about:blank", "_blank", "location=no");
    browser.show()

    //inject html code to blank page. one time
    browser.on("loadstop")
      .subscribe(
      (sucess) => {
        if (!injected) {
          browser.executeScript({ code: "document.write('" + this.paymentGatewayDetails + "');" }).then(
            (sucess) => {
              console.log("sucess");
              browser.executeScript({ code: "document.mypg.submit();" }).then(
                (sucess) => {
                  console.log("sucess redirection");
                }, (err) => {
                  console.log("error redirection");
                }
              );
            }, (err) => {
              console.log("err")
            }
          );
          injected = true;             
        }
        console.log("success url is", sucess.url);
        if (sucess.url.includes("mobile.mypg.com")) {
          //payment gateway call sucess.
          browser.close()
          resolve("PG_CALL_SUCC")
        }
      }
      )}
```

> We had given in PLIST file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
   <dict>
       <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
       <true/>
   </dict>
```

> And in INDEX.html>

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src gap://ready file://* *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';”>
```

> **We had installed the Whitelist plugin also**
>
> **cordova-plugin-whitelist**

**In config.xml added these lines also**

```
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

> **cordova plugin ls**
>
> com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot 0.1.5 "Screenshot"
>
> cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.3.3 "ActionSheet"
>
> cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
>
> cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
>
> cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
>
> cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.3 "Notification"
>
> cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2 "FCMPlugin"
>
> cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
>
> cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.7 "Globalization"
>
> cordova-plugin-hotline 1.2.1 "Hotline plugin for Phonegap"
>
> cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"
>
> cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2017072706 "IBM MobileFirst Platform
>   Foundation"
>
> cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore 8.0.2017081712 "IBM MobileFirst Platform
>   Foundation JSONStore"
>
> cordova-plugin-nativestorage 2.2.2 "NativeStorage"
>
> cordova-plugin-okhttp 2.0.0 "OkHttp"
>
> cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 2.0.1 "Screen Orientation"
>
> cordova-plugin-sms 1.0.5 "SMS"
>
> cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
>
> cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"
>
> cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
>
> cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.8 "SocialSharing"
>
> cordova.plugins.diagnostic 3.6.6 "Diagnostic"
>
> es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
>
> ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
>
> uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator 4.0.4 "Launch
>   Navigator"
>
> **Please help us to fix this issue...**

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your cordova plugins.  `ionic cordova plugins ls`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.

`browser.executeScript({ code: "document.write('" + this.paymentGatewayDetails + "');" });` is works for IOS and Android

Here I had removed the **.then(
                (sucess) => {**

> Now the new code which is working in both IOS and Android

```
    callGateway() {  
 return new Promise(
   (resolve, reject) => {

    let injected = false;

    if (!this.paymentGatewayDetails) {
      reject("PG_DET_INVALID")
    }

 const browser = this.iab.create("about:blank", "_blank", "location=no");
    browser.show()

    //inject html code to blank page. one time
    browser.on("loadstop")
      .subscribe(
      (sucess) => {
        if (!injected) {
          browser.executeScript({ code: "document.write('" + this.paymentGatewayDetails + "');" });
              console.log("sucess");
              browser.executeScript({ code: "document.mypg.submit();" }).then(
                (sucess) => {
                  console.log("sucess redirection");
                }, (err) => {
                  console.log("error redirection");
                }
              );           
          injected = true;             
        }
        console.log("success url is", sucess.url);
        if (sucess.url.includes("mobile.mypg.com")) {
          //payment gateway call sucess.
          browser.close()
          resolve("PG_CALL_SUCC")
        }
      }
      )}
```

> I don't know why it is not works there. If someone knows it please answer.
>
> Thanks